# How route traffic to a Azure SQL server via a jump server to prevent whitelistingof dev machine?

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, development

I have to connect to Azure SQL server (e.g. mydatabase.azuredb.windows.net:1433). In order to do so, i have to inform my ADMIN to whitelist my machine's IP, works fine that day. NExt day my machine restarts and i get a another IP address. I have to inform and wait for whitelisting and cycle continues. We work using VPN and have a server which (windows, onpremise) behind the VPN and has static IP.

Is is possible to route Azure SQL server traffic from my machine via this server?

Comment: That would be called a "proxy"; there's plenty of options to be found via your favourite search engine.

Comment: Here is what I found. [Connect to Azure SQL Server from computer with dynamic external IP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62216654/connect-to-azure-sql-server-from-computer-with-dynamic-external-ip). Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You may want to configure a [private link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/private-link-overview#key-benefits) and  NGINX TCP Proxy to connect your on-premises network to Azure SQL Database. [Here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-database-support-blog/lesson-learned-316-connecting-to-private-endpoint-of-azure-sql/ba-p/3731257) you will find how to configure it.

Comment: Hi Alberto will this work if IP of source changes post restart, will this not require that extra effort about which OP is worried ?

Comment: Yes Shanky, you can go ahead and connect from on-premises with the private IP address and you no longer depend on the public IP address changes of the Azure SQL logical server.